# Complex choropleth map for IE8

Tags: dictionary, internet-explorer-8, visualization, vml

I'm trying to set up a [choropleth map](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html) for US counties, either as a layer on a map service (for example, using leaflet) or as a plain SVG/VML figure.

The thing is: whereas Chrome or Firefox render either option perfectly, IE8 does not handle so many polygons, and its loading times are unacceptable.

Before falling back to generating static PNGs server side, do you know any lightweight component (not Flash-based) that can generate such a visualization in IE8? Thank you!

Comment: Some more detail would help here--you've mentioned that "loading times are unacceptable" on IE8; that would suggest that you've tested either a layer on a map service or SVG/VML--which one is it?  Also, indicating why Flash is not an acceptable alternative here will help in determining acceptable solutions.  How about some sample code?

Answer (score 1):

In increasing order of complexity :

Creating a choropleth map can be done very easily with [Tableau](http://www.tableausoftware.com/public/blog/2011/04/choropleth-counties). The visualization can be exported and made interactive. Tableau is not a free software, but you will have a trial period to try it.

We also had [students](http://cs171.org/) implementing their choropleth map using [D3](http://blog.visual.ly/how-to-make-choropleth-maps-in-d3/) with the map imported using JSON. As far as I know, this didn't pose problems with IE, although I didn't specifically test them on IE.

Finally, the winning team in one of our course contest created a map (although not a choropleth, they still visualized data on it) using [Processing](http://processing.org/). This usually involves more coding (Java-like), but doable and you can test their visualization on an IE8 browser (at [this link](http://tweetography.herokuapp.com/) - the visualization is very slow to load but this is more due to their extraction of tweeter feeds rather than the map itself).

In general, you can see our students' visualization at [this URL](http://cs171.org/projects/project-list.php), several of them having map visualizations - and you can browse technologies used for choropleth maps at the [visualizing.org](http://visualizing.org/) website.